# How to round to 1 floating point in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to plot the bar graph.

```
import pandas.util.testing as testing
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
# import matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label as bar_label
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
df = testing.makeTimeDataFrame(freq='MS')
ax = df.A.plot(kind='bar')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]);
```

It produces this plot:

[image]

How can round it to 1 floating point. Using a format such as this `"{:.1f}".format(45.34531)`. I am unsure of how to apply it. Without it, the plot is illegible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.1f')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using labels:

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df['A'].round(1))
```